# libgdx why doesn't the Camera follow the character?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new with libgdx and I have read a Tutorial (the Tutorial Code is my base).
I have a character that I can move, but the camera won't follow the character :(

Here's my WorldRenderer.java:

```
package com.evolutio.tee.view;

import com.evolutio.tee.model.Block;
import com.evolutio.tee.model.Tee;
import com.evolutio.tee.model.World;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;

public class WorldRenderer {

    private static final float CAMERA_WIDTH = 10f;
    private static final float CAMERA_HEIGHT = 7f;

    private World world;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;

    /** for debug rendering **/
    ShapeRenderer debugRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

    /** Textures **/
    private Texture teeTexture;
    private Texture blockTexture;

    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private boolean debug = false;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private float ppuX; // pixels per unit on the X axis
    private float ppuY; // pixels per unit on the Y axis

    public void setSize (int w, int h) {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        ppuX = (float)width / CAMERA_WIDTH;
        ppuY = (float)height / CAMERA_HEIGHT;
    }

    public WorldRenderer(World world, boolean debug) {
        Tee tee = world.getTee();
        this.world = world;
        cam = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        cam.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2f, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2f, 0);
        cam.update();
        this.debug = debug;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        loadTextures();
    }

    private void loadTextures() {
        teeTexture = new  Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tee/tee.png"));
        blockTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("world/dreck.png"));
    }

    public void render() {
        spriteBatch.begin();
            drawBlocks();
            drawTee();
        spriteBatch.end();
        //if (debug) drawDebug();
    }


    private void drawBlocks() {
        for (Block block : world.getBlocks()) {
            spriteBatch.draw(blockTexture, block.getPosition().x * ppuX, block.getPosition().y * ppuY, Block.SIZE * ppuX, Block.SIZE * ppuY);
        }
    }

    private void drawTee() {
        Tee tee = world.getTee();
        spriteBatch.draw(teeTexture, tee.getPosition().x * ppuX, tee.getPosition().y * ppuY, Tee.SIZE * ppuX, Tee.SIZE * ppuY);
        cam.position.set(tee.getPosition().x, tee.getPosition().y, 0);
    }

    private void drawDebug() {
        // render blocks
        debugRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        debugRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Rectangle);
        for (Block block : world.getBlocks()) {
            Rectangle rect = block.getBounds();
            float x1 = block.getPosition().x + rect.x;
            float y1 = block.getPosition().y + rect.y;
            debugRenderer.setColor(new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));
            debugRenderer.rect(x1, y1, rect.width, rect.height);
        }
        // render Tee
        Tee tee = world.getTee();
        Rectangle rect = tee.getBounds();
        float x1 = tee.getPosition().x + rect.x;
        float y1 = tee.getPosition().y + rect.y;
        debugRenderer.setColor(new Color(0, 1, 0, 1));
        debugRenderer.rect(x1, y1, rect.width, rect.height);
        debugRenderer.end();
    }
}
```

at drawTee() I try to make the camera following the Tee.

```
cam.position.set(tee.getPosition().x, tee.getPosition().y, 0);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
public class WorldRenderer {

private static final float CAMERA_WIDTH = 10f;
private static final float CAMERA_HEIGHT = 7f;

private World world;
private OrthographicCamera cam;

/** for debug rendering **/
ShapeRenderer debugRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

/** Textures **/
private Texture teeTexture;
private Texture blockTexture;

private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
private boolean debug = false;
private int width;
private int height;
private float ppuX; // pixels per unit on the X axis
private float ppuY; // pixels per unit on the Y axis

public void setSize (int w, int h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    ppuX = (float)width / CAMERA_WIDTH;
    ppuY = (float)height / CAMERA_HEIGHT;
}

public WorldRenderer(World world, boolean debug) {
    Tee tee = world.getTee();
    this.world = world;
    this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    this.cam.setToOrtho(false,CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    this.cam.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2f, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2f, 0);
    this.cam.update();
    this.debug = debug;
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    loadTextures();
}

private void loadTextures() {
    teeTexture = new  Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tee/tee.png"));
    blockTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("world/dreck.png"));
}

public void render() {
    moveCamera(tee.getPosition().x, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2);
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    spriteBatch.begin();
        drawBlocks();
        drawTee();
    spriteBatch.end();
    //if (debug) drawDebug();
}

public void moveCamera(float x,float y){
    if ((tee.getPosition().x > CAMERA_WIDTH / 2)) {
        cam.position.set(x, y, 0);
        cam.update();
    }

}


private void drawBlocks() {
    for (Block block : world.getBlocks()) {
        spriteBatch.draw(blockTexture, block.getPosition().x, block.getPosition().y, Block.SIZE, Block.SIZE);
    }
}

private void drawTee() {
    Tee tee = world.getTee();
    spriteBatch.draw(teeTexture, tee.getPosition().x, tee.getPosition().y, Tee.SIZE, Tee.SIZE);
}
```

Using the sprite.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined) before the spriteBatch.begin() is needed because if you don't the spriteBatch uses it's own camera, therefore your updates do nothing for what appears on screen.
   You have to take out the ppuX, ppuY stuff. I know that's to resize the screen for different devices, but it screws up the camera, therefore if you keep it in and call the setProjectionMatrix, it will be way way zoomed in (actually the size of all images will be huge.)

Comment: Also, with this the camera will stay at the same height you set it at initially, if you try to set it to your characters Y position, it will be too low. If you're using the Star Assualt tutorial as a base, which I'm about 100% sure you are.

Comment: Hey, 
I can't test it :( 
I've destroyed any on the code :'( 
At work the code has work, but at home it don't work.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/OXGC2.png

Comment: You deleted all your code? If you used dropox you could get the code anywhere.

Comment: No I'dont delete it.
I copy the two folders from work on my sdcard from the handy, and from the sdcard to the PC.
I go into Eclipse > File > Import > General > Existing Workbench > an then I select the folder where the two folder's inside.

Comment: Hmm, should work, sometimes if your setup is different you may have issues on different computers. I've got one that won't run my desktop version of my project.

Comment: No problem, I was having the same issues. Used code from another answer on here.